# How to do remote debugging of DLL in delphi 7 from scratch

Tags: delphi, remote-debugging

can anyone please help me out, to how to do remote debugging of a DLL (Just a dll) which is independent of the exe.
The dll is a service which will be running in the server machine and the DLL source code is at the client machine. Now when this service is running at the server machine i want to debug the delphi code which is at the client machine using delphi 7.

Answer (score 4):

1. Compile the DLL with remote debugging symbols and deploy both (.dll, .rsm, etc) on the server machine
2. Install the remote debugger on the server machine
3. Start the remote debugger on the server machine
4. Start Delphi on the client machine and load the DLL project
5. Start a remote debugging session from Delphi by choosing Run - Attach to process and fill in the server machine
6. Select the process on the server machine which loaded the DLL
7. Debug remote

Also see http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Remote_Debugger

Comment: 1. compiled dll with remote debugging options,i have set these values in project options-Linker
2. Installed the BORdbg70.exe [Remote debugger] on the server machine. After installing, i could see the green colored Bug in the taskbar.
3. start remote debugger means how to do?
4. at the client machine i have opened the DLL project.
5. frm client machine, i went to the RUN-Attach to process and after giving the server machine name,listed all the process of the server machine. 
6. selected the process of the DLL.
got error 
BORdbg70.exe-BORdbk70.Dll"Internal Error EVA-1528".

Comment: please help me out for getting solution for this. It is very urgent.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it right. I don't know about that internal error. Sorry.