# Delphi "Internal Error EVA 1528"

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-7

Can anyone please help me out in rectifying the error: BORdbg70.exe BORdbg70.dll "Internal Error EVA 1528".
What is the cause of this error? how can i slove this problem.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922225/how-to-do-remote-debugging-of-dll-in-delphi-7-from-scratch) how the remote debugging session was setup

Answer (score -1):

An internal error is a bug in the compiler. See this

[Article about what to do in case of internal compiler errors](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/wiki/InternalErrors.ashx)

for some hints what you can do.

Two things that often solved the problem for me:

- Restart the IDE
- Remove all DCU files of your project and build it from scratch

Comment: In this case it comes from the debugger, not the compiler.